# neo4j Get list of new nodes (change-feed)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, scalability

Is there a way on Neo4j to fetch a list of all the new nodes created after a certain time? like a built in change-feed?

I know this could be done by traversing the **entire** graph and comparing if a node's date is > than the treshold set before.

However, this is not optimal at the very least and would not perform well on a 10 million node graph.

Is there a way to know if new nodes were added? (or relationships) some sort of change feed like a built in bloom filter?

If not, any ideas on getting a change feed every x minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried an [INDEX](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/)? With an index your query performance will be improved. Try creating an index in the property related to the creation time of the nodes.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(created_at)
```

After, when creating a node, you can use the [timestamp()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-timestamp) function and save the current timestamp in the property `created_at` of `:Person` nodes.

```
CREATE (:Person {name:'Jon', created_at: timestamp()})
CREATE (:Person {name:'Doe', created_at: timestamp()})
```

Then you can query normally by the `created_at` property of `:Person` nodes and the index will be used.

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.created_at > 1502882338889 // given a timestamp...
RETURN p
```

Also, if you don't need all the nodes modified after a given timestamp at same time, you can make a pagination in the query and work with pieces of the entire data using [SKIP](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/skip/) and [LIMIT](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/limit/).

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.created_at > 1502882338889 // given a timestamp...
RETURN p
ORDER BY p.created_at
SKIP 1
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, but, can an index be created on a graph that already has nodes? Because by your example (And other examples I've read) they create indexes BEFORE the creation of nodes... But I already have a lot of data in my graph

Comment: @KevinCohen Yes, an index can be created on a database that already has nodes. [The docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/#schema-index-create-a-single-property-index) says that  the index is not immediately available, but will be created in the background.

Comment: Thanks again Bruno!

Comment: Hey bruno quick question, you gave an example where the created_at property is a timestamp(). Currently I have my created date property as a string. This is fine because I can still do: where n.created > '2017-08-16 16:34:32.00' for example. But, is this affecting performance? How do I know if the index is actually being used? How is the index implemented? I did some tests with /without index on 1 million nodes and did not find a big difference...

Comment: @KevinCohen Once an index is created it will be used by the query planner. You can use [PROFILE and EXPLAIN](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) to see it. I don't know if the performance difference between these cases are noticeable, but I believe that use a string for comparing and ordering dates is not a good idea. See an example: if you compare the **integers** 2 and 10, so the expression 2 > 10 is false. But if you compare the **strings** "2" and "10", the expression "2" > "10" is true. In some cases your comparison will break.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152104/discussion-between-kevin-cohen-and-bruno-peres).